# paypal iOS integration

Tags: objective-c, ios, paypal

I did button and when I pressed it call this method and on iPhone simulator 5 I got error and on iPhone simulator 4.3 work success but after more than one touch on button:

```
- (void)simplePayment {
//dismiss any native keyboards

[PayPal initializeWithAppID:@"APP-80W284485P519543T" forEnvironment:ENV_SANDBOX];

//optional, set shippingEnabled to TRUE if you want to display shipping
//options to the user, default: TRUE
[PayPal getPayPalInst].shippingEnabled = TRUE;

//optional, set dynamicAmountUpdateEnabled to TRUE if you want to compute
//shipping and tax based on the user's address choice, default: FALSE
[PayPal getPayPalInst].dynamicAmountUpdateEnabled = TRUE;

//optional, choose who pays the fee, default: FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER
[PayPal getPayPalInst].feePayer = FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER;

//for a payment with a single recipient, use a PayPalPayment object
PayPalPayment *payment = [[[PayPalPayment alloc] init] autorelease];
payment.recipient = @"example-merchant-1@paypal.com";
payment.paymentCurrency = @"USD";
payment.description = @"Teddy Bear";
payment.merchantName = @"Joe's Bear Emporium";

//subtotal of all items, without tax and shipping
payment.subTotal = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"10"];

//invoiceData is a PayPalInvoiceData object which contains tax, shipping, and a list of PayPalInvoiceItem objects
payment.invoiceData = [[[PayPalInvoiceData alloc] init] autorelease];
payment.invoiceData.totalShipping = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"2"];
payment.invoiceData.totalTax = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.35"];

//invoiceItems is a list of PayPalInvoiceItem objects
//NOTE: sum of totalPrice for all items must equal payment.subTotal
//NOTE: example only shows a single item, but you can have more than one
payment.invoiceData.invoiceItems = [NSMutableArray array];
PayPalInvoiceItem *item = [[[PayPalInvoiceItem alloc] init] autorelease];
item.totalPrice = payment.subTotal;
item.name = @"Teddy";
[payment.invoiceData.invoiceItems addObject:item];

[[PayPal getPayPalInst] checkoutWithPayment:payment];
```

}

**Error on iPhone 5 simulator**

```
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFConstantString
> rangeOfString:options:range:locale:]: nil argument'
> 
> *** First throw call stack: (0x142df1c 0x15c052e 0x13cfd38 0x13cfcaa 0xd00681 0xd0e35c 0x5400e 0x6a373 0x70958 0x6e823 0x543d9b 0x765be
> 0x763a1 0x545144 0x5453bb 0x546138 0x4b5b41 0x4bb031 0x4b531f 0x51fb
> 0x9889 0x54de 0x34df 0x2ff4 0x48084c 0x4807e2 0x52777a 0x527c4a
> 0x526ee4 0x4a6002 0x4a620a 0x48c60c 0x47fd52 0x1b968f6 0x13fd31a
> 0x1358d07 0x1356e93 0x1356750 0x1356671 0x1b950c3 0x1b95188 0x47dc29
> 0x294c 0x2885 0x1) terminate called throwing an exceptionsharedlibrary
> apply-load-rules all Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
> (gdb)
```

**Should I use paypal button?**

```
UIButton *button = [[PayPal getPayPalInst] getPayButtonWithTarget:self andAction:action andButtonType:type];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mobile Payment Libraries iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300906/mobile-payment-libraries-ios)

Answer (score 0):

Library Support for the devices and OS versions.
The Mobile Payments Library fully supports OS 4.0 as well as the Apple iPad. You can compile the library files into the following configurations:

> • 3.0, 3.1.x (iPhone only)
>   • 3.2 (iPad only)
>   • 3.x (Universal)
>   • 4.x

The demo application also fully supports OS 4.0 and the Apple iPad. You can compile the demo
application into the preceding configurations.
The single library file can be used to support armv6 and armv7 architectures for SDK 4.0 and below. Support is only provided for Xcode 3.2.3 at this time.